# Data logging on a SIM5320

Tags: datalogger, modem, sim, 4g

One of my SIM5320 devices is using a lot more data than before while sending a POST message to a web server. I like to see what connections the SIM5320 is establishing, but i don't know how. What is the best way to do this?

I prefer to log all data and connections on the device. But I can't find whether it is possible to connect a laptop with Wireshark to the module, for example.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid EE question.

Comment: Run everything though a vpn (maybe)